# Exponential Smoothing for many time series

Tags: time-series, forecasting, multivariate-analysis, exponential-smoothing

I have a detailed dataset with a lot of time series.

If I apply exponential smoothing (using for instance **R**) it will take me to much time to calculate an $\alpha$ (level parameter) and $\beta$ (trend parameter) for each time series.

Therefore, is there a scientific method you can apply when you have a lot of time series (maybe by calculating a pooled $\alpha$ and $\beta$ or something like that).

Comment: How many time series? How long are the time series? What frequency? How far ahead do you want to forecast?

Comment: You can use the r package smooth to chose the best, in predicting the data, exponential smoothing model. This will allow you to do them a lot faster - although that is different than you asked I know.